# While-Loop in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, while-loop

i want just a simple while-loop in JSF.

Something like :

```
<c:set var="i" value="0"/>
<c:while #{act.observation[i].value !=null}>
<td style="width: 12%;">#{act.observation[i]} /></td>
<c:set var="i" value="${i + 1}" />
```

Of course i know there is nothing like **c:while** and i have tried **c:forEach** and **ui:repeat**, but couldn't figure out how this could have worked, especially with xml paths (rims) that i am using.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a very bad idea. You are generating a page so you should know when to stop repeating.

Comment: Looks like you are looping until you don't have a value.  You could add an extra property on the bean that determines the numerical value of when the value become null and use that upper limit in a c:forEach or ui:repeat.

Comment: @helderadarocha: This is not that simple, since this is a routine for displaying unknown amount (comes from migrating and can vary from 1 to 1000) of entries from generated xml.

Comment: Do while i < {act.observations.length } may need to check is not null too, why not us a datatable, your cod. Implies it's in a ta. Anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{act.observation}" var="observ">
    #{observ}<br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Where observation is your list of items you want to print.